# SBJson won't go as deep in NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, nsdictionary, sbjson

I've been banging my head on the wall all day because of this.

I'm trying to parse this JSON blob [here](http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/suiz.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=VLkwpNTnRVSqquwvmRFtHVKHFE8IUad8ImPXx87JKfWyID9ASb).

This is what I'm using:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue];

NSArray *allTweets = [[results objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"posts"];
```

However, when I try to do this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[[[aTweet objectForKey:@"posts"] objectForKey:@"photos"] objectForKey:@"original_size"] objectForKey:@"url"]];
```

It gives me no error but the *url is set as "null".

I've used CFShow for the NSDictionary but everything after the "photos" key comes out as a regular string and not JSON formatted.

Can anyone tell me why?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Even though "one-liners" seem nice, when dealing with JSON it's almost always wiser to break each step in the traversal of a data structure into a separate line.  It's easier to see when you've missed a step, and much easier to debug.  The difference in efficiency (if indeed there is any) is negligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < [[[results objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"posts"] count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"url data = %@",[[[[[[[results objectForKey:@"response"]
        objectForKey:@"posts"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"photos"]
        objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"original_size"] objectForKey:@"url"]);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that was it! I was missing the objectAtIndex:0 THANKS!